# php regular expression for "|" and digits

Tags: php, regex

I want know, what regular expression should I have for my string. My string can contains only "|" and digits.
For example: "111|333|111|333". And string must begin from number. I am using this code, but he is ugly:

```
if (!preg_match('/\|d/', $ids)) {
    $this->_redirect(ROOT_PATH . '/commission/payment/active');
}
```

Thank you in advance. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your example I assume you are looking for a regex to match string that begin and end with numbers and numbers are separated with `|`. If so you can use:

```
^\d+(?:\|\d+)*$
```

Explanation:

```
^      - Start anchor.
 \d+   - One ore more digits, that is a number.
 (?  ) - Used for grouping.
 \|    - | is a regex meta char used for alternation, 
         to match a literal pipe, escape it.
  *    - Quantifier for zero or more.
$      - End anchor.
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex is:

```
^\d[|\d]*$

^   - Start matching only from the beginning of the string
\d  - Match a digit
[]  - Define a class of possible matches. Match any of the following cases:
    |   - (inside a character class) Match the '|' character
    \d  - Match a digit
$   - End matching only from the beginning of the string
```

*Note: Escaping the `|` is not necessary in this situation.*

Comment: I know the OP does not really specify it, but this would also allow sequences like `123||456|` (double pipe and pipe at the end).

Comment: @Felix Well... yes. It follows the requirements. codaddict's answer would be better if he wants to enforce a digit as the last character.

Answer (score 1):

A string that contains only `|` or digits and begins with a digit is written as `^\d(\||\d)*$`. That means: either `\|` (notice the escape!) or a digit, written as `\d`, multiple times.

The `^` and `$` mean: from start to end, i.e. there’s no other character before or after that.

Answer (score 1):

I think `/^\d[\d\|]*$/` would work, however, if you always have three digits separated by bars, you need `/^\d{3}(?:\|\d{3})*$/`.

EDIT:
Finally, if you always have sequences of one or more number separated by bars, this will do: `/^\d+(?:\|\d+)*$/`.